# In C# (VS-2010), is there a way to fail a frontend build if a certain library class is used? (When normally it would compile just fine?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a library that has a bunch of classes in it which are intended to be used by multiple frontends (some frontends share the same classes). For each frontend, I am keeping a hand edited list of which classes (of a particular namespace) it uses. If the frontend tries to use a class that is not in this list, there will be runtime errors. My goal is to move these errors to compile time.

If any of you are curious, these are 'mapped' nhibernate classes. I'm trying to restrict which frontend can use what so that there is less spin up time, and just for my own sanity. There's going to be hundreds of these things eventually, and it will be really nice if there's a list somewhere that tells me which frontends use what that I'm forced to maintain. I can't seem to get away with making subclasses to be used by each frontend and I can't use any wrapper classes... just take that as a given please!

Ideally, I want visual studio to underline red the offending classes if someone dares to try and use them, with a nice custom error in the errors window. I also want them GONE from the intellisense windows. Is it possible to customize a project to do these things?

I'm also open to using a pre-build program to analyze the code for these sorts of things, although this would not be as nice. Does anyone know of tools that do this?

Thanks

Isaac

Comment: You should simply compile different assemblies for different frontends.

Comment: Can't you separate the classes by projects? So, you can just use the class (and intellisense) where there's a reference to it.

Comment: @Skomski - no, I can't do this.. there's going to be a lot of shared code between frontends, and because of this data access library I'm using there's no way to move the shared stuff out of these classes in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say that you have a set of classes `F`. You want these classes to be visible only to a certain assembly `A`. Then you segregate these classes in `F` into a separate assembly and mark them as `internal` and set the `InternalsVisibleTo` on that assembly to true for this certain assembly `A`.

If you try to use these classes from any assembly `A'` that is not marked as `InternalsVisibleTo` from the assembly containing `F`, then you will get a compile-time error if you try to use any class from `F` in `A'`.

> I also want them GONE from the intellisense windows. Is it possible to customize a project to do these things?

That happens with the solution I presented above as well. They are internal to the assembly containing `F` and not visible from any assembly `A'` not marked as `InternalsVisibleTo` in the assembly containing `F`.

However, I generally find that `InternalsVisibleTo` is a code smell (not always, just often).

Comment: Bad solution for his problem because he doesnt want to control access to the file. Makes more problems then it solves. GL maintaining.

Answer (score 2):

You should club your classes into separate dlls / projects and only provide access to those dlls to front end projects that are 'appropriate' for it. This should be simple if your front-end and the *group of* classes it may use are logically related.

If not then I would say *some thing smells fishy* - probably your class design / approach needs a revisit.

Comment: Well, that would be nice, but right now it's not entirely clear which frontends are going to use what, because I'm not even sure what they all do yet. I have to rewrite frontends over a huge legacy database. I guess if I could be sure that certain code was only going to be used by one frontend then I could put it in its own frontend specific dll. Since I can't be sure of this I'm opting for this route so it's easy for each frontend to use whatever with just minimal code changes

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to take a look at the ObsoleteAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

I believe you can set IsError to true and it will issue an error on build time.

(not positive though)

As for the intellisense you can use EditorBrowseableAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx  Or at least that is what seems to get decorated when I add a service reference and cannot see the members.

Comment: Another way to make it an error is to use `/warnaserror:612`. This might be useful if you need to use it somewhere without errors, by saying `#pragma warning disable 612`.

Comment: I can't mark these classes as obsolete, because for some frontends they are allowed and some they aren't, and all the classes reside in the same library project.